# Searching tags with metawhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, meta-where

I'm trying to perform a multi-column search on a model and it's associated tags.  I'm using metawhere and acts-as-taggable-on for this.  Basically I have a model with a title and body that has a certain amount of tags with names.  I've been trying to set this query up with metawhere but it never returns any results when I try to join to a model's tags.  I have a variable named "str" that's being used to search a Post model with the following...

```
Post.where(:title.matches % '#{str}%' | :body.matches % '#{str}%' | {:tags => [:name.matches % '#{str}%']}).joins(:tags)
```

which generates the following sql...

```
=> "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `posts`.`id` = `taggings`.`taggable_id` AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Post' INNER JOIN `tags` ON 'taggings.tagger_id IS NULL AND taggings.context = \\'tags\\'' WHERE (((`posts`.`title` LIKE '\#{str}%' OR `posts`.`body` LIKE '\#{str}%') OR `tags`.`name` LIKE '\#{str}%'))"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste in the sql which is generated from this query?

Comment: I forgot to wrap the str variable in #{} and added the generated sql to my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: (assuming operator overloads are enabled)

```
.where((:title =~ str) | (:body =~ str) | {:tags => [:name =~ str]})
```

Comment: for some reason this is giving me a type mismatch error, saying "type mismatch: String given".

Comment: I forgot to turn operator overloads on, now I don't get that type mismatch error but it doesn't seem to be searching tags.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using this metasearch dynamic finder...title_or_body_or_tags_name_or_taggings_tag_name_contains